# Count of li for empty ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am running the following code to find the count of li in ul.

```
     <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {      
           $("ul").each(function(index) {
              alert($(this).find('li').size());         
           });

       });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <ul/>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul><li>li1</li><li>li2</li></ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

I get the alerts as 2, 0, 2. Why am I getting the count of li in  as 2? 
How can I get it to be 0?

Comment: THIS Could be browser dependant, on how it handles ul/  try replacing with the conventional ul /ul.  Or,  limit find to depth 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HTML != XHTML
```

If your header is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, replace

```
<ul/>
```

by

```
<ul></ul>
```

Only SVG and MathML elements can be self-closing in a proper HTML4 or HTML5 (not XHTML) document.

Answer (score 4):

You can't self-close a ul tag like this `<ul/>` (in HTML, at least) so it is wrapping your other two `ul` elements and containing each `li` recursively.  Close your ul tag correctly like the second one and it works.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your first ul tag wraps other ul tags. Now the first ul tag has 2 li tags that belongs to the third ul. Your markup is invalid and you we'll get different results in different browsers.